# How to unproperly encode my HTML chunk so it is displayed properly in my page

Tags: html, encoding, decoding

I need to retrieve some HTML tags from a database to display in my page. But when the web server outputs the query result (a small html chunk), it encodes the HTML before outputing on the page.

Example : `<a>` becomes `&lt;a&gt;`

**The server behavior cannot be changed. If I could change it, I would!**

Is there a way I can encode my HTML chunk before storing it in db so when the server renders the page, the chunk gets encoded/decoded(?) and it gets displayed properly ?

I'm not sure it's even possible.

Comment: Can you show some code or give some details about what platform you are using etc?

Comment: What platform/application/technology are you using to pull the content from the DB and generate the HTML page to display to the user and/or push the content into the DB?

Comment: The question is platform-agnostic, else I would have put it in the question's description. The platform is Cognos 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If the output stage is HTML-encoding data it fetches from the database, that's because it is designed to handle the database content as text, and is deliberately not allowing HTML output. That's usually what you want to do, as if someone can inject data into the database that displays as raw HTML, you've potentially got cross-site-scripting security problems.

If you want raw HTML output, you must change the output stage to not escape markup characters. There is no possible “more unencoded than raw” format that would output raw HTML when encoded.

Comment: It's a private web site, so there is no xss security concerns. But from what you are telling me, there is no way to 'trick' the server to encode so it gets transform in valid html. I tought so.